# Laravel - MethodNotAllowedHttpException error on getting post data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting following error when receiving post data from another site to my blade template. How can I display these data in my view?

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ 
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

Comment: Can you please share your code here so we can help you more precisely? asked by @Shreeraj

Comment: It seems like there's a mismatch in the expected request type and the request that is actually being received. Laravel treats `Post` `Put` and `Patch` differently, so double check to make sure the other site is actually sending a post request and you are accepting the post request (`php artisan route:list`) on that route.